# FormData object is empty even though it is being set when trying to send a pdf file as a multipart FormData POST request in Cypress

Tags: javascript, typescript, automated-tests, cypress

I want to send the pdf file as a POST request.

The API accepts `@RequestPart` and `@RequestParam`:

```
@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file;
@RequestParam(value = "document-types", required = false) Set<String> documentTypes;
```

I tried to do it that way:

```
it('test', () => {
    cy.fixture(pdfFilePath, "binary").then(file => {
        const data = new FormData();
        data.set('file', file);
        data.set('document-types', 'New Type');
        cy.request({
            method: "POST",
            url: '/api/v4/documents',
            headers: {
            accepts: "multipart/form-data",
            authorization: authString
            },
            body: data
        }).then((response) => {
            expect(response.status).to.eq(200)
        });
    });
});
```

And when I run this I get:

`Status: 400 - Bad Request`

In Cypress I see that body in request sent is empty:
`Body: {}`

[image]

When I tried to debug the code, I see that `data` is being sent empty as you see on the attached screenshot:

[image]

And I wonder why because I try to set the `data` by doing these steps in lines 154 and 155 on the above screenshot:

```
data.set('file', file);
data.set('document-types', 'New Type');
```

What am I missing here?

Cypress version: `9.0.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Christopher mentioned in the answer,`data` was not empty. I had to use [`data.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/get) or simply [`data.get()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/get) to view the content.

But anyways I was not able to make that code working.

Instead, I followed the approach presented in [this](https://youtu.be/M7ofat3ZI4s?t=1120) youtube video and it worked.

```
it.only('test', () => {
    function form_request(method, url, formData, done) {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url);
        xhr.setRequestHeader(
            "Authorization",
            "Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4="
        );
        xhr.onload = function () {
            done(xhr);
        };

        xhr.onerror = function () {
            done(xhr);
        };

        xhr.send(formData);
    }

    const fileName = "PdfFileName.pdf";
    const method = "POST";
    const url = '/api/v4/documents';
    const fileType = "application/pdf"

    cy.fixture(pdfFilePath, "binary")
        .then((txtBin) => Cypress.Blob.binaryStringToBlob(txtBin))
        .then((blob) => {
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("file", blob, fileName);
            formData.append("document-types", "New Type");
            form_request(method, url, formData, function (response) {
                expect(response.status).to.eq(200);
            })
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to append formData, code below is just an example:

```
    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('file', files[0])
    formData.append('name', files[0].name)
```

Comment: I tried with `append` as well. It's not the cause. But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not empty, you have to make use of [`data.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/entries) to view the content.

It seems like the cy.request() function tries to convert the FormData Object to a JSON object which is wrong.

From the [documentation of cypress](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/request#Arguments) you should also make also use of the `form: true` setting.

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData
- https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-formdata

Comment: Many thanks for the comment. I can clearly now see the content of `data` when I do `data.get('file')` in the console while debugging. I also added `form: true` to the headers. Unfortunately I still don't know how to solve my problem. Do you have any ideas what I could do next?

Comment: Not really, I haven't worked with Cypress before. But I'm glad to hear it helped debugging. :)